# Text redacting when line limit set

Tags: swift, swiftui, word-wrap, truncate

I'm having an issue in SwiftUI where I have a container and then a view within the container which contains text. I need the text to wrap and for the container to expand to its height. Here is a very simplified version:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                
                VStack {
                    Text("hellloooo")
                        .frame(width: 151.5, height: 202)
                    
                    Text("klfaskjfkaslfjaslkfjklfaskjfk")
                        .frame(maxWidth: 151.5, alignment: .leading)
                        .lineLimit(3)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Like this, I'm getting the following:

[image]

I had thought that setting the line limit with wrap the text rather than have it truncated like this. I tried adding the following modifier:

```
.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

This stopped the text from truncating but the container view does not expand:

[image]

I also tried adding a `Spacer()` at the end of the VStack. This did push the content, however, when I have only 1 line of text, the Spacer is still adding additional space at the end of the view, which I do not want. How do I get around this issue?

Comment: Are you looking to increase the size of the red container when the lines wrap? Or are you envisioning the wrapped text to remain inside the bounds of the red container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems to be the problem:

```
.frame(maxWidth: 151.5, alignment: .leading)
```

The view works as desired, if I'm understanding your need, when width is used instead:

```
.frame(width: 151.5, alignment: .leading)
```

Resulting in this:

[image]

The complete code (your original code with the fixedSize() and that small change):

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 10) {
                VStack {
                    Text("hellloooo")
                        .frame(width: 151.5, height: 202)
                    
                    Text("klfaskjfkaslfjaslkfjklfaskjfk")
                        .frame(width: 151.5, alignment: .leading)
                        .lineLimit(3)
                        .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                }
            }
            .background(Color.red)
            .padding(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Such a small change! Thanks a lot :)